# Editing a question for mathematical inaccuracy not entirely related to the original query

Tags: discussion, editing

An [edit was suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1882595) for a [somewhat old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516263/difference-between-cantors-ordinals-and-von-neumann-ordinals) where the question contained a mathematical inaccuracy which could mislead others. (This edit does not directly relate to the question being asked.)

The reason for doing this is that the inaccuracy *did* lead to me wasting at least a couple of hours due to being misled.

The suggested edit appears to have been rejected for reasons that are not entirely clear to me. Hence, I have left two comments on the original post which explain the nature of the inaccuracy which should help others who find themselves misled.

However, I believe that it is a good idea for questions to be corrected for mathematical inaccuracies as people *may not* always search through the comments.

Am I wrong?

Comment: IMHO, better left as a comment: the OP did correctly copy the Wolfram definition. If you think Wolfram is wrong, the good way is not to change the intent of the question. The OP never said Wolfram is wrong, you did. You may be right, but it looks weird to modify the question to fit another definition found elsewhere.

Comment: In general, such edits are absolutely appropriate.  In this case, though, the question is actually very specifically about the incorrect Mathworld definition, and would not really apply to the correct definition.  This is not because of the error that you corrected but because of a second error in the definition, where it says "proper subset" instead of "subset".

Comment: In general, editing inaccuracies in a post can be tricky because they might be the underlying cause of the asker's issues. That might explain some of what you're running in to here.

Comment: EricWofsey and KReiser Thanks for your clarifications. I did notice the second error you pointed out and that it led to the OP's question. However, until EricWofsey's recent answer to the post, it seemed to me that the other (first) error had been missed entirely. Since it took me a while to notice the first error, I thought of correcting it. It is indeed true that erroneous quotations from erroneous sources can be difficult to "fix" by a simple edit of the question.

Comment: I agree with @Jean-ClaudeArbaut.  Correcting a math error made by the OP asker or in answers can be done in a comment to the author.  Suggested edits, and edits in general, should not be imposed into a post.  Comment, if you see an error.  Or in the case of an answer, post your own answer that you believe is correct.